# Jquery Validation - Range 0 to 100 Not Working Correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the Jquery Validation plug-in and I couldn't get it working correctly. What I like to validate is only allowing using enter range from 0 to 100 in the field, not allow 0.1, .5, -11.4.  Currently, if I enter 0.5, it recognizes a valid number even though I set the range: [0, 100].

Fiddle Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/milacay/e4fe4hsz/3/

I have two questions:

1. How can I only allow whole number from 0 to 100 (Not 44.3, but 44.0 is OK)?.  If this is not possible, I can live with 44.3 for now.
2. How can I allow decimal number says from 0.5 to 50? Example, valid numbers are 0.6, .7, 0, 3, 49, but invalid numbers are 0.45, 0.2, 51 or greater.

Thanks in advance,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Makes "field" required and between 0 and 100.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">

</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Required, minium 0, maximum 100:</label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      range: [0, 100]
    }
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Currently, if I enter `0.5`, it recognizes a valid number even though I set the range: `[0, 100]`.*

That's because the `range` rule accepts decimal numbers.  Since `0.5` is greater than zero, it's valid.

> *How can I only allow whole number from 0 to 100 (Not 44.3, but 44.0 is OK)?*

Just add the `integer` rule (*part of [the additional-methods.js file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/additional-methods.js)*).

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            integer: true,  // <- here
            range: [0, 100]
        }
    }
});
```

The default `digits` rule should work just as well in this case, since you don't have any negative numbers.  IMO, since you just want to exclude decimal numbers, stick with `integer` so if your `range` ever needs to go negative, you will not break it.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/e4fe4hsz/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/e4fe4hsz/5/)**

---

> *How can I allow decimal number says from 0.5 to 50?*

You are already doing this; it's what you're complaining about in question #1.

*(Obviously, you cannot simultaneously allow and disallow decimal numbers, so not sure what this part of the question is really all about.)*

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            range: [0.5, 50]  // <- here
        }
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/e4fe4hsz/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/e4fe4hsz/7/)**

Comment: what is the difference between `integer:true` and `digits:true`? It seems the default rules including `digits:true` not `integer:true`

Comment: `integer` can be a positive or negative whole number.  `digits` only accepts numbers: `-`, `,`, or `.` are not allowed.  In your case, either rule should work.

Comment: *it's what you're complaining about in question #1*, that's the most hilarious comment I've ever seen on SO :). The irony is, it is not a joke, it's fact :).

Comment: @Sparky, I am not the OP, i am just curious on `integer:true`, because I didn't find `integer:true` from [List of built-in Validation methods](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).

Comment: @Sphinx, `integer` is part of the `additional-methods.js` file that the OP is already using in his jsFiddle.  I've edited my answer accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky, I am the beginner of the JQuery validate, then not aware of `additional-methods.js`. Thanks your patience.

Comment: integer: true works great.  Thank you for your help.  BTW, I am just trying to learn, not complaining.... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Milacay Sparky didn't mean it that way. It's just another way of saying that you're asking how to do what you're already doing, but it's more hilarious to say it that way. Don't worry about it, we're all learning from each other here. Your questions were good, +1.